# How can I get Text from a google document?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a google document and I can append text easily but I need a code receive text from that google document.

like this

var textb = body.getText() etc...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getText() {
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body=doc.getBody();
  Logger.log(body.getText());
  return body.getText();
}
```

- [DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#getActiveDocument())

Comment: thanks for your answer but does not work.  this is my doc and  script link..."https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-50vVkmjAaO-Y6OUaXVtsoqSUs2h4pRUQ9WAwddgDO8/edit"   https://script.google.com/d/1NsSZG57jbUk2zKiFqKGoDxhR6vuunq64KRkC61Fm3lRLN1fp7IMp_7W6/edit

Comment: in your code do I need to place something into the paranthesis of"getActiveDocument"like

var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(document url or id etc) ?